# Java (Spring-Boot) Ошибка при загрузки файла (размером больше 1 МБ) на сервер

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

использую **Windows + Java8 + maven + Spring-Boot (v2.4.10)**.

С клиента пробую загрузить файл на сервер. При этом возникает такая ошибка:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileItemStreamImpl.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:76) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2922) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2824) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1202) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1036) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_291]
```

Мой контроллер, который обрабатывает запрос:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public String postProcess(@RequestParam ("desc") String desc, @RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile[] masFiles) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ParseException {
    System.out.println("Request: toProcess");
    
    //Передать на обработку данные desc и массив файлов masFiles
    String response = Main.dictionary.synchronizeAccess(12, "", masFiles);
        
    return response;
}
```

Почитал советы и пробовал создать файл конфигурации **application.properties** в папке **resource** с таким содержимым:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

При этом ошибка все равно возникает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно еще попробовать, чтобы решить эту проблему, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас возникла такая ситуация, то можно попробовать следующее решение:

1. Добавить этот **код** в файл с классом, в котором происходит запуск **spring-boot** приложения:

```
@Bean //Метод для установления размера файла и размера запроса
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        
    factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.parse("10MB")); //Установить значение в 10MB
    factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.parse("10MB")); //Установить значение в 10MB

    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

2. Добавить зависимости:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;
```

---

В целом ваш класс должен выглядеть примерно таким образом:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling 
@EnableAsync 
public class ThreadSpringServer { 
    
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context; //Config spring app
    
    public ThreadSpringServer(){}
    
    //Метод для запуска spring server
    public void start(){
        System.out.println("Start spring server");
        context = SpringApplication.run(ThreadSpringServer.class);
    }
    
    //Метод для остановки spring server
    public void stop(){
        System.out.println("Stop spring server");
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean //Метод для установления размера файла и размера запроса
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();

        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.parse("10MB"));
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.parse("10MB"));

        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

Подобное сработало у меня на версии **Spring-boot v2.4.10**.